# invalid command name "1775568714624update" in customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

**when I trying to make more than one interface in customtkinter lib,
I face Error like that given below and my program stuck,
I have never face this problem in normal tkinter
**

invalid command name "1775568714624update"
while executing
"1775568714624update"
("after" script)
invalid command name "1775530397696check_dpi_scaling"
while executing
"1775530397696check_dpi_scaling"
("after" script)
invalid command name "1775587007232_click_animation"
while executing
"1775587007232_click_animation"
("after" script)

```
from customtkinter import (CTk, CTkButton)

def fun():
    root.destroy()
    inp = CTk()
    inp.mainloop()

root = CTk()
root.geometry('250x250')
but = CTkButton(master=root, width=50, height=25,text="TEST" ,command=fun).pack(expand=True) 
   
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very bad practice. As a general rule of thumb you should never create more than one instance of a root window, or call `mainloop` more than once.

In this specific case, customtkinter uses the `after` command to handle the animation of the button. However, in between the button being pressed and released you're destroying the root window. That makes it impossible for the `after` command to run since it has been destroyed.

If you want to be able to destroy and recreate root windows, the better solution is to put your entire UI in a frame, and then destroy and replace that frame while keeping the root window intact.

It might look something like this:

```
from customtkinter import (CTk, CTkButton, CTkFrame)

def fun():
    global f
    f.destroy()
    f = CTkFrame(master=root)

root = CTk()
root.geometry('250x250')
f = CTkFrame(master=root)
f.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
but = CTkButton(master=f, width=50, height=25,text="TEST" ,command=fun).pack(expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Though, it's best to move the creation of your UI into a function or class definition.